# Prometheus invalid metric type "status=\"available\"} gauge" + 401

Tags: prometheus, arangodb, arangodb-foxx

Trying to monitor with Prometheus, but cannot get /_admin/metrics/v2/ to work with jwt (I've confirmed the token matches web, tested with postman). So I've enabled the `arango-prometheus-exporter` service, and can read metrics from the mount point `/metrics`.

However, Prometheus is now reporting `invalid metric type "status=\"available\"} gauge"` in the targets list page, and the endpoint is shown as `down` in red.

I am unsure of 3 things:

1. Why do I get a 401 `not authorized to execute this request` when using a valid jwt bearer token,
2. Why am i getting `invalid metric type "status=\"available\"} gauge"` for the prometheus target endpoint using the foxx-service mounted at /metrics,
3. Should i even be using the foxx-service, or the internal admin metrics url?

I am using the latest as of a couple days ago, ArangoDB v3.10.1, Prometheus v2.41.0-rc.0 (and Grafana v9.3.2 (21c1d14e91) but i haven't gotten that far with ArangoDB yet).  All on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.

I am currently successfully monitoring Prometheus, Node exporter and RabbitMQ.

**UPDATE: I should be using the ArangoDB metrics rather than Foxx.**  More info on issues using built-in metrics:

I have generated a secret from arangodb on command line using `arangodb create jwt-secret`, then used `arangodb auth header --auth.jwt-secret secret.jwt` to generate the auth header string.  I copy the token to `/etc/prometheus/prometheus.token` and update prometheus.yml to:

```
  - job_name: "arangodb"
    scrape_interval: 5s
    metrics_path: /_admin/metrics/v2
    bearer_token_file: /etc/prometheus/prometheus.token
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["localhost:8529"]
```

Then i restart prometheus to pick up the changes, and in the Targets tab i see

[image]

I tested by running as sudo to generate the secret from ArangoDB, then sudo to generate the Bearer Token, but still the same result.

However, if I copy the token from the jwt key from the Application tab in devtools from the ArangoDB site and paste it into Postman Authorisation section under Bearer Token and make a GET request to `http://172.31.245.140:8529/_admin/metrics/v2/` it does work.

So I copied the same token from website login to `/etc/prometheus/prometheus.token`, restart Prometheus and now its working.  But, it will only last until the web token times out. <- And confirmed, jwt token has timed out and Prometheus is showing "server returned HTTP status 401 Unauthorized" again.

Am I missing something?

**UPDATE 2 - I can connect using basic auth in the prometheus config.**

So this works:

```
  - job_name: "arangodb"
    scrape_interval: 5s
    metrics_path: /_admin/metrics/v2
    #bearer_token_file: /etc/prometheus/prometheus.token
    basic_auth:
      username: root
      password: the_password
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["localhost:8529"]
```

I didn't try password_file instead, but that would at the least remove password from the config file.  I'm ok with this for now since it will be locked down, but i would rather use token auth.

Comment: As the original author of arango-prometheus-exporter I can tell you that it is deprecated and that you should use the built-in metrics instead. This endpoint also provides much more metrics that were not available in foxx. What exactly was your problem with the authentication? Can you share details about the request and the error response?

Comment: I just updated my question to include more info on the auth issue.  I'm happy to use the built-in metrics.

Comment: Regarding the JWT token - I think when creating the token it should be possible to specify the token lifetime. Alternatively, you can use basic authentication as you already established with the root user. However, you don't have to use root, you can create a specific user for prometheus. You only have to ensure that this user has read access to the `_system` database.

Comment: Unfortunately its not the timeout that's the issue, but can't use the server generated one.  however, as you say it is working with basic auth so that's a viable solution. And true, I don't have to use root, didn't know about read access to _system, thanks for the info.